# Providing Entity-Relationship in DB?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am designing a database regarding to supermarket or department store which have branches all over the world.

I have the list of countries and branches. Will any one help me to link them in database.

Comment: read a book on databases, and data model patterns. go on amazon.com

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

Of course, your tables will contain more columns to store additional data - but this would be the basic skeleton.

Or what exactly are you asking? You're not being very clear in your question ....

T-SQL code to generate this (adapting this for MySQL should be no problem at all):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Country
(
    CountryID int NOT NULL,
    CountryName varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Country 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Country PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CountryID)  
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.State
(
    StateID int NOT NULL,
    StateName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CountryID int NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.State 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_State PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (StateID) 

ALTER TABLE dbo.State 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_State_Country 
FOREIGN KEY(CountryID) REFERENCES dbo.Country(CountryID)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.City
(
    CityID int NOT NULL,
    CityName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    StateID int NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.City 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_City PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(CityID) 

ALTER TABLE dbo.City 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_City_State 
FOREIGN KEY(StateID) REFERENCES dbo.State(StateID)  
GO
```

Comment: @marc_c has given you a great answer but I would hope that before applying it you make sure there is a need for normalized data, as there are some cases where a denormalized schema is beneficial.

Comment: @Kane: always start with **normalized** data model - it's the proper thing to do! I'd only denormalize if the normalized model hurts (e.g. performance or something)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need three tables (country, city and state) with an id and a table for the supermarkets referencing the ids in country, city and state.

```
create table country(id int, name varchar);
create table city(id int, name varchar);
create table state(id int, name varchar);
create table supermarket(country int, city int, state int);
```